# В чем разница между ThreadGroup, ThreadPool, ThreadPoolExcecutor, Excecutor и ExcecutorServise?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Недавно начал изучение многопоточности в джава и столкнулся с этими понятиями. Они все вроде служат для организации потоков, но в чем их разница?

Answer (score 1):

В java есть два интерфейса для многопоточности 
[Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)
и [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Всё класс которые имплементятся от `Runnable`, значений не возвращают.
Те которые имплементятся от `Callable` возвращают значения.

ThreadGroup неудачный класс судя по книге: **Эффективное программирование, Джошуа Блох**

Дальше смотрите в документации каждый класс, и задавайте более точные вопросы, так как данный вопрос слишком общий

Answer (score 1):

Дополню принятый ответ.

`Executor` это интерфейс для запуска `Runnable` без возможности управления процессом исполнения.

`ExecutorService` это тоже интерфейс для запуска как `Runnable`, так и `Callable`, плюс управление самим процессом исполнения.

ThreadPoolExecutor это одна из имплементаций обоих интерфейсов.