# Java: Как запустить поток повторно на android?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Java я знаю нормально. Но android приложения начал учится делать недели 2 назад.
Уже сделал несколько activity, и начал делал авторизацию. Но, есть проблема, когда я ввожу верные логин и пароль, меня пускает дальше. Если я ошибусь в логине или пароле, то мне выведет ошибку, я введу верный логин и пароль. А ничего и не происходит, то есть поток в котором у меня запрос к http, не запускается повторно.

Простите за код, он очень корявый и детский.

Layout не важен.

Вот код

```
package com.tut.moy.package;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button buttonLogin, register;
    EditText inputLogin, inputPassword;

    TextView StatusType, StatusMessage;
    LinearLayout StatusBar;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    
    private Intent Intent = new Intent();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Handler interval = new Handler();
    
    static ArrayList<String> html = new ArrayList<String> (1000);
    private String response = "none";
    private Boolean RepResponse = false, started = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        inputLogin = findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        
        StatusBar = findViewById(R.id.StatusBar);
        StatusType = findViewById(R.id.Status);
        StatusMessage = findViewById(R.id.StatusMessage);
        
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(Intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
            
        
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(response != "sended"){
                response = "sended";
                try
                {
                    login();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
            }

            
                
                
            
        }
        });
    }
    
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String login = inputLogin.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.myserve.secret/projects/gd02/v1/User.Login/email=" + login + "&password=" + password +"");
                InputStream xx = null;
                try {
                    xx = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( xx ));
                    String line = "";
                    try {
                        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                            html.add(line);
                        }
                        response = html.get(0);
                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err adding", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err close", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }       
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err stream", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err url", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            
            }
        });
    
    Thread t_interval = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(response == "sended"){
                interval.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }else{
                StatusBar.setVisibility(1);
                StatusType.setText("");
                StatusMessage.setText(response);
                progressDialog.hide();
                RepResponse = true;
            }
        }
    });
    
    
    void login() throws Exception{
        
        
        progressDialog.setMessage("Авторизация");
        progressDialog.show();
        
        th.start();
        t_interval.start();
    }
    
}
```

(простите если есть орфографические ошибки)
Помогите пожалуйста, начинающему android программисту.

Comment: Говорите Java знаете "нормально"? It is never legal to start a thread more than once. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Comment: Не знал о таком . Буду искать решение.

Comment: Не нашёл решение. Я читал про потоки но не использовал их. Думал будет легче.

Comment: а зачем вам именно поток? Почему бы не воспользоваться библиотеками для отправки запроса, которые правильно всё обрабатывают

Comment: Поток создал-запустил-забыл о нем. Создавайте просто новый, если надо еще раз операцию выполнить. А лучше почитайте о thread executors. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1103514/184031

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже нашёл решение. Сейчас его оубликую

Answer (score 0):

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            }else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
    return responseString;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //убераю загрузку
        LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
        //тут обработка ответа...
    }
}
void login(){
    //Создаю загрузку
    LoadingBar.setVisibility(1);
    StatusBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
    //получаю данные из формы в переменные
    String login = inputLogin.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    
    //дедаю запрос к серверу передавая данные.
    new RequestTask().execute("https://api.myserver.mooo.com/projects/Clicker/v1/User.Login/email=" + login + "&password=" + password);
}
```

Весь этот код в главном классе. При нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод login() ну а дальше уже будет запрос.

Comment: Библиотеки не использовал потомучто я рукожоп. Я их усанавливал и из-за них проект не компелировался. Хотя другие библиотеки подключаю и всё работает. Вот и решил без библиотек делать. Пробовал подключать volley, retrofit2

Comment: Сейчас буду код выше оптимизиртвать. И под себя класс обработчик сделаю.